# Floating Header

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to put the `h1` element next to the picture (both in the header `div`). What do I need to do to achieve this?

```html
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
    <img src="eye.png" style="height:inherit;">
    </div>
    <div class="motto">
        <h1>We can do it!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways you could do this. One easy way would be to make your logo and motto divs `display: inline-block`

```css
.logo, .motto {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="eye.png" style="height:inherit;">
  </div>
  <div class="motto">
    <h1>We can do it!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.header{display:flex;align-items:center;}` or you can use `.logo, .motto {display: inline-block;}`